# AngularJS finally not executed if promise is notify

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

In my AngularJS application I'm trying to use `finally` in `$http` call.

This is my service

```
app.service("webResource", function($http, $q) {
    return {
        post : function(url, json) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.post(url, json)
            .success(function (data, status) {
                if (data!=null) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                } else {
                    defer.notify("Send notify....");
                }
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                defer.reject({"response":data, "status": status});
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

In my controller I have

```
$scope.callServer = function() {
    var promise = webResource.post('someurl',$scope.data);
    promise
    .then(
        function(data) {
            alert("Success");
            //Do for success
        },
        function(data) {
            alert("Error");
            //Do for failure
        },
        function(data) {
            alert("Notify");
        }
    ).finally(function() {
        alert("Finally");
    });
};
```

If it's resolved or rejected, it's working fine. But if it's notify it alerts **"Notify"**, but then not alerting **"Finally"**. Why is that?

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.2 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.finally` takes two callbacks in the following form:

`.finally(callback, notifyCallback)`

You are currently only passing a single callback to your `finally` handler, as such you will only trigger the `alert('Finally!)` on either `resolve` or `reject`.

Add a second callback to the `.finally` step and you *should* be seeing a callback triggered when you do `deferred.notify`.

**[docs ($q.promiseAPI)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)**

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't go to finally is because you can have multiple notifies. From the docs:

"notify(value) - provides updates on the status of the promise's execution. This may be called multiple times before the promise is either resolved or rejected."

Finally is once the promise is completely finished (both resolve and reject finish the promise)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api